# AS3 action listener unresponsive

Tags: actionscript, actionlistener

In a mini game I made, I wanted to add a simple restart level button.  All goes well during the first run of the game, but after hitting the restart button (which essentially just unpauses it by flipping a few booleans and such) the action listener to move the character in the game isn't responding.  I put a trace() of a boolean switch for the action before and after hitting reset, and prior the value is correctly being displayed, but after the value is not.

Any ideas?  I know I'm probably going to be asked to post my code, but it's quite long and unorganized, so I'm curious if there is a known issue relating to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this action listener is tied to your resetting the game, my first guess is that your game is not loosely coupled, in which case the answer is no, there are no known related issues apart from the fact you're probably experiencing problems due to a bad structure.

If you admit that the code is long and unorganized, you may just have defined the place you need to start from.

It would probably be worth your while to look at the game structure and do some refactoring.

For instance , your game character, should be fairly independent from the rest of the game's code. You should almost be able to take it and import it in another game if you wanted.

Look into OOP, and see how by separating concerns and reducing dependencies, your game will be easier to debug, upgrade and improve.

That's about as much as I can say without looking at any code!